# openshift postgres persistent volume permissions

Tags: postgresql, openshift

The postgres image I am currently deploying with openshift is generally working great. However I need to persistently store the database data (of course) and to do so i created a persistent volume claim and mounted it to the postgres data directory like so:

```
- mountPath: /var/lib/pgsql/data/userdata
  name: db-storage-volume
```

and

```
- name: db-storage-volume
  persistentVolumeClaim:
    claimName: db-storage
```

The problem I am facing now is that the initdb script wants to change the permission of that data folder, but it cant and the directory is assigned to a very weird user/group, as the output of `ls -la /var/lib/pgsql/data` indicates (including the failing command output):

```
total 12
drwxrwxr-x. 3 postgres root      21 Aug 30 13:06 .
drwxrwx---. 3 postgres root      17 Apr  5 09:55 ..
drwxrwxrwx. 2 nobody   nobody 12288 Jun 26 11:11 userdata
chmod: changing permissions of '/var/lib/pgsql/data/userdata': Permission denied
```

How can I handle this? I mean the permissions are enough to read/write but initdb (and the base images initialization functions) really want to change the permission of that folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as I had sent my question I had an idea and it turns out it worked:

- Change the mount to the parent folder `/var/lib/pgsql/data/`
- Modify my entry script to include a `mkdir /var/lib/pgsql/data/userdata` when it runs first (aka the folder does not exist yet)

Now it is:

```
total 16
drwxrwxrwx. 3 nobody     nobody 12288 Aug 30 13:19 .
drwxrwx---. 3 postgres   root      17 Apr  5 09:55 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 2 1001320000 nobody  4096 Aug 30 13:19 userdata
```

Which works. Notice that the folder itself is still owned by `nobody:nobody` and is 777, but the created `userdata` folder is owned by the correct user.